# Why Reuse Yeast?

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters, reusing-yeast, harvest

Sorry for seeming clueless, but I am clueless. I've only brewed about 15 batches, or less, of extract beers. Thus far, I've always bought prepackaged recipe "kits" similar to a Betty Croker cake mix.
Since finding this site, I am seeing a lot of questions regarding washing, rinsing and reusing yeast, but I havent seen (found) a reason why you wold? Is it just economical?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly economical, yes.

Another reason is potentially limited (or non-existent) commercial availability of specific strains. Either the yeast company's seasonal strain releases or something cultivated from yeast remaining in the bottle.

Another reason is to develop a "house" strain, or to modify the behavior of an existing strain. For instance, the good-ole Wyeast 1056/WLP001/US-05 is indicated as becoming extremely attenuative after a number of serial re-pitchings.

Comment: OK that all makes sense. I have a long way to go when it comes to the science of brewing. Now I know why master brewers have huge beards, they spend so much time "learning" that they dont have time to shave! :)

Comment: The beard thing is interesting. I was noticing that just today.

Comment: Maybe they grow their yeasts in their beards? SCNR.

Comment: @Robert I don't know if you were referring to this or not, but in case you hadn't heard of it ... http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/32736/title/Beard-Beer/

Answer (score 0):

Also for high gravity beers this can be helpfull.  If you brew a big IPA and have a large yest cake at the bottom, you can put a barley wine or IRS on it and it will ferment much faster.  Just make sure the fermentation went well first!